# Is “characteristic” an abstract noun?

Tags: abstract-nouns, concrete-nouns

Colour is a characteristic, but it’s concrete.

Shape is a characteristic, but it’s abstract.

Then, “characteristic” can be both an abstract noun and a concrete noun?

Comment: What do you mean by concrete? What do you find concrete about colour?

Comment: @Ronald Sole Concrete means existing in a material or physical form; not abstract. And Colour is the definite concrete noun. We can see it.

Comment: We can see shapes as well!

Comment: @Kate Bunting Oh no can we see size as well?

Comment: You can see the difference between a big helping of food and a small one, can't you?

Comment: @Kate Bunting https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/292386/are-shape-and-size-abstract-nouns but they are abstract nouns.

Comment: In his answer to that question James says _There is also a considerable grey area between "abstract" and "concrete"._  I don't see that 'colour' is any different from 'size' and 'shape' in this respect.

Comment: @Kate Bunting Then, something can be an abstract noun even though we can see. But I’m curious. What’s the reason that linguistics divide concrete nouns and abstract nouns.

Comment: I suppose because it is convenient for some purposes when discussing language. See [here](https://www.grammar-monster.com/glossary/abstract_nouns.htm) under "Abstract or concrete? It could be ambiguous".

Comment: @Kate Bunting Can I ask silly question? Can we see redness and blueness?

Comment: @Kate Bunting I’m really wondering we can see blue but can’t see blueness?

Comment: @Kate Bunting Pleeeeese I promise I will not ask about this topic. Please teach me sad face sad face

Comment: Blueness is the quality of being blue. You can see that something is blue, so I suppose it could be argued that you can see blueness.

Comment: @Kate Bunting Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, 'characteristic' is abstract. As a general rule, if you can say something exists but you can't touch it, it is abstract.

'Characteristic' is a term for many other things which in turn may be either abstract or concrete, but without additional detail, you cannot say if those 'characteristics' are tangible or not.

For example:

> He has many defining characteristics.

Those characteristics referred to could be entirely intangible. For example, '*boldness*' may be a characteristic of someone. That is an intangible concept, so 'boldness' is an abstract noun and an abstract characteristic.

However, you might say a person has 'big eyes'. Eyes are a physical thing, and not an abstract noun. So while the word 'characteristic' is abstract, specific characteristics may or may not be.

Comment: I don’t understand “characteristic” can be for a concrete thing, but how is “characteristic” always an abstract noun?

Comment: @GatePending **A** characteristic can be concrete, or not. But the word characteristic itself isnt'.